# CoreData Crashing Upon Deletion and More

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have some really mysterious behaviour with CoreData.

I'll add an `Object`. I save this object. I fetch the new results and reload the collection view (from which is display the objects). The new object shows up. Hoorah! Just as expected.

I do this a second time, but every time from now (unless the app is restarted) when re-fetching the data from my `NSFetchedResultsController` and reloading the collection view, the new object doesn't appear.

Equally, if I delete an object. First time, A-OK! The next time I do this, the app actually crashes with the following error:

(`Aircraft` is my `NSManagedObject`)

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://C418948D-90CD-40E9-A502-C4CAB0134419/Aircraft/p3>''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18b79f09c 0x197ad5d78 0x18b4a77ac 0x18b4a6cac 0x18b4a6b00 0x100034438 0x18e6d8a44 0x18e6d6dc0 0x18e6d2e44 0x18e66ed78 0x18e26b0cc 0x18e265c94 0x18e265b4c 0x18e2653d4 0x18e265178 0x18e25ea30 0x18b75f7e0 0x18b75ca68 0x18b75cdf4 0x18b69db38 0x19106f830 0x18e6dc0e8 0x1000217dc 0x1980bfaa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type _NSCoreDataException
```

Time for some code. I can't see any issues, but here it is. I won't spam you with everything, but if something rings any alarms, I can always add it on request.

Starting with the main view controller. This contains my collection view. Just as a note, it has two sections each fetching data from an individual `NSFetchedResultsController`. I am only seeing the issue with this specific one though. Fairly standard fetched results controller.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)aircraftFetchedResultsController
{
    if (_aircraftFetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _aircraftFetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Aircraft" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:50];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.aircraftFetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.aircraftFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _aircraftFetchedResultsController;
}
```

Anywhere I use an `NSManagedObjectContext` I am getting it from my `AppDelegate`. When adding the new object, the user is in a modal (form sheet) view controller. I create a new object, but do not insert it immediately, incase the user cancels:

```
SLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Aircraft" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        self.aircraft = [[Aircraft alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

Then, when done, save the object:

```
SLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //Only need to insert the new object if its 'NEW' else just save the existing one we are editing
    if (!isEditing)
    {
        //Create new aircraft
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        //We are definetly saving the object, so now we insert it
        [managedObjectContext insertObject:self.aircraft];
    }

    //Save
    [appDelegate saveContextWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL didSaveSuccessfully) {
        if (didSaveSuccessfully)
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                [delegate addAircraftDidSave:YES];
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                 //ALERT with error
            }];
        }
    }];
```

I use a delegate to send a message back to the main view controller saying the object has saved. That method then fetches the new data and reloads the collection view to show the new object:

```
-(void)fetchAircraft
{
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self aircraftFetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        [UIAlertView showGenericErrorAlert];
    }
    //Success, we have results
    else
    {
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Done. As I said, this works first time, then start acting up. Equally, you can substitute the save code for the delete code I have, fairly similar, delete and save changes:

```
SLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
            [managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.aircraft];

            [appDelegate saveContextWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL didSaveSuccessfully) {
                if (didSaveSuccessfully)
                {
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                        [delegate addAircraftDidSave:YES];
                    }];
                }
                else
                {
                    //ALERT with error
                }
            }];
```

Comment: Do the two fetched results controllers use different cache names? You can also try `cacheName:nil`. I *think* that without sections, the FRC cache is not really needed.

Comment: And after all of that, that appears to have solved it! While the second fetched results controller was working as expected, I thought the solution would to be mirror the code as closely as possible match match the functionality. That resulted in them sharing a cache, causing all sorts of issues. Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)* The two fetched results controllers must use different
caches (`cacheName:` parameter). I also *think* (but I am not 100% sure about that)
that without sections, a cache does not give any advantages, so you can also
try `cacheName:nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to use separate ManagedObjectContexts for saves on a background thread.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html